# (canvas) Push a new item every couple seconds

Tags: javascript, html, animation, canvas

Hello and thank you for your help in advance.

I am trying to push/create a new "ring" every couple seconds. I have a ring with a couple variables for the X and Y. The problem I am encountering is, how do I get a new ring and also increment the variables? I need a new variable name for every ring?
Here is how far I have gotten so far:

http://codepen.io/hossman/pen/AfwkF

You can see in the demo how 1 ring goes out, but I want more than 1 ring to go out of my eyes. So for instance 1 ring goes and then it waits a second and then shoots out another ring, so now there are 2 rings on the canvas, then 3, then 4, etc.... I have thought of multiple ways like using arrays and setTimeouts, but I cant put my finger on it. The only other idea I have is to create multiple variables with different names and have each ring be incremented, but thats not very D.R.Y.

Anyhelp?

Please ask questions if I didn't explain it good enough. Thanks again!

Comment: Can I have a try?  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/QQ57C/

Comment: @markE haha woah! Pretty awesome!!! Love StackOverflow. So many talented people that are willing to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to your global vars at the top (and set to whatever you want the distance to be between circles):

```
var distanceApart = 40;
```

Then update your main loop like this:

```
requestAnimationFrame(function print() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    var leftRing = new Ring(x, y);
    var rightRing = new Ring(x2, y2);
    var temp = startRadius;
    var temp2 = 0;

    while(temp > 0){
         leftRing.draw(ctx, startRadius - temp2 , 'red');
         rightRing.draw(ctx, startRadius - temp2 , 'red');   
         temp2 = temp2 + distanceApart;
         temp = temp - distanceApart;
    }

    startRadius += increase;

    requestAnimationFrame(print);
});
```

Forked here: **http://codepen.io/anon/pen/plBmj**
(Looks very memorizing!)

Comment: Hit refresh on the FORK if it doesn't immediately start. Weird glitch on my browser sometimes with codepen. And wait for the circle to get big enough and you'll start to see the next one starts.

Comment: Holy smokes! Thank you kind sir! You're incredible. I am very grateful for what you have done. You have helped me so much. Thanks again!! :-)

Comment: I know I already thanked you, but seriously thank you. I love the way you wrote it to. I am going to keep that in mind. Not sure why I didn't think of the while loop. Thanks for increasing my knowledge.

Answer (score 2):

I would rewrite parts of your code to enable this. For example I would rewrite your `Ring` class as follows:

```
var Ring = defclass({
    constructor: function (x, y, r) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.r = r;
    },
    draw: function (context) {
        context.beginPath();
        context.arc(this.x, this.y, this.r, 0, Math.PI * 2);
        context.stroke();
        return this;
    },
    addRadius: function (r) {
        return new Ring(this.x, this.y, this.r + r);
    }
});
```

Your `Ring` class constructor now takes `x`, `y` and a radius `r`. The `addRadius` function returns a new `Ring` instead of mutating the original one. This is good because immutability makes your code easier to work with. Oh, and `defclass` is declared as:

```
function defclass(prototype) {
    var constructor = prototype.constructor;
    constructor.prototype = prototype;
    return constructor;
}
```

Then we create the two rings for your eyes:

```
var radius = 10;
var delta = 0.1;

var left = new Ring(cx - (cx / 3.6), cy - 5, radius);
var right = new Ring(cx + (cx / 3.6), cy - 10, radius);
```

After that we call the animation loop:

```
var interval = 50 / 3;
var start = Date.now();
loop(start, [left, right]);
```

Since we want to playback at 60 FPS the interval is `1000 / 60` which can be simplified to `50 / 3`. The animation loop is defined as follows:

```
function loop(last, rings) {
    var next = last + interval;

    context.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);

    var newRings = rings.map(function (ring) {
        return ring.draw(context).addRadius(delta);
    });

    var now = Date.now();

    setTimeout(loop, next - now, next,
        Math.floor((now - start) / 1000) === rings.length / 2 ?
            [left, right].concat(newRings) : newRings);
}
```

Here's what's happening:

1. First we clear the screen.
2. Then we draw all the rings and increase their size.
3. If one second has elapsed we add two new rings to the array.
4. Finally we calculate when to call `loop` again so that it fires after the correct `interval`.

See the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/LAr76/

Comment: oh man. Thats awesome!!  UGG! Sorry I gave the answer to the other guy, but yours is great to! I am actually very appreciative that you took the time to explain and write it out. Ahh man. Sorry you didn't get answer. But THANK YOU SO MUCh for answering. I am going to examine both of your guys' code. Again im sorry you didnt get *answer* but it works great. I +1 it. Thanks guys!! :-)

Comment: Man you did some awesome things. I don't understand a lot of it, but like I said before I am going to examine it. I don't know much about ternary and stuff, but its cool to see it in action. Thank you!!